# How to Calculate Gap Between two Dates in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a data set as shown in the picture.
I am trying to get the date difference between eligenddate (First row) and eligstartdate (second row). I would really appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: what version of tSQL?  SQL Server or Sybase?  What version of those databases?

Comment: Hi Stuart,I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: What defines the order of rows to be compared? A table has no intrinsic order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL2005:

One solution is to insert into a table variable (@DateWithRowNum - the number of rows is *small*) or into a temp table (#DateWithRowNum - the number of rows is *high*) the rows with a row number (generated using `[elig]startdate` as `order by` criteria; also see note #1) plus a self join thus:

```
DECLARE @DateWithRowNum TABLE (
    memberid    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    rownum      INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(memberid, rownum),
    startdate   DATETIME NOT NULL,
    enddate     DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT  @DateWithRowNum (memberid, rownum, startdate, enddate)
SELECT  memberid, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY memberid ORDER By startdate),
        startdate, 
        enddate
FROM    dbo.MyTable

SELECT  crt.*, DATEDIFF(MONTH, crt.enddate, prev.startdate) AS gap
FROM    @DateWithRowNum crt 
LEFT JOIN @DateWithRowNum prev ON crt.memberid = prev.memberid AND crt.rownum - 1 = prev.rownum
ORDER BY crt.memberid, crt.rownum
```

Another solution is to use common table expression instead of table variable / temp table thus:

```
;WITH DateWithRowNum AS (
    SELECT  memberid, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY memberid ORDER By startdate),
            startdate, 
            enddate
    FROM    dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT  crt.*, DATEDIFF(MONTH, crt.enddate, prev.startdate) AS gap
FROM    DateWithRowNum crt 
LEFT /*HASH*/ JOIN DateWithRowNum prev ON crt.memberid = prev.memberid AND crt.rownum - 1 = prev.rownum
ORDER BY crt.memberid, crt.rownum
```

Note #1: I assume that you need to calculate these values for every `memberid`

Note #2: HASH hint forces SQL Server to evaluate just once every data source (`crt` or `prev`) of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you Bogdan as always.